# Should I use "nor" in "It's inconvenient to access Facebook nor Google in China"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to express that it's very hard to access Facebook and it's very hard to access Google in another way, can I say "It's inconvenient to access Facebook nor Google in China" or "It's inconvenient to access Facebook or Google in China"?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/should-i-use-or-or-nor On a side note, *and* fits here better than *or/nor*

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'or'. 'Nor' is used in conjunction with 'neither':

> Neither Facebook nor Google is conveniently accessible in China

Comment: Thanks! Can "nor" be used without "neither"? If can, in what occasion?